# Connect 2 2K monitors to a M1 mini via Thunderbolt 4 dock?

Tags: thunderbolt-display

I get this ( https://www.qgeem.com/products/type-c-hub-12-in-1-dp ) USB docking, at Windows 10 I can use extended display, but in Mac mini M1 it is only mirroring the display

I just wonder if there is some way for Mac OS to try an "extended" display?

Comment: To be sure: in System Preferences -> Displays _> Display Settings...you are not given the "Use as: Extended display" option for the second monitor?

Comment: Yes, already done that, look like a limitation of Mac OS

Comment: I don't think so, I use a Thunderbolt hub for my second monitor. However, I only use it for the second monitor. I use the built in HDMI for my primary monitor.

Comment: Right that is my current setup, but I would like to connect both of my monitors with Thunderbolt hub, so that when I switch the hub to another computer I don't need to switch another HDMI also

Answer (score 0):

I use a Display Link Adapter to connect a second 4k display to my M2 Mac

Comment: Thanks, I ultimately like to do is easier to switch the dock to a different computer, and now I need to switch the dock, and also an HDMI cable only for my 2nd monitor